# How to put core plot legend titles to the left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

By default the titles of the legend are on the right, and the swatches are on the left. Is there a way to switch their position by putting the titles to the left?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not right now. You can post an enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).